# httppost method of android doesnt work with namevalue pairs

Tags: android, post, http-post

The code below creates a form whose results are to be posted to server(request to a server)... i tried the same form using html with same form fields it works but here it does not work and redirects to the home page of the website.....

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
Button submit,fpass;
EditText wbpasswd,wblogid;
TextView loginid,password;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    wblogid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.wblogid);
    wbpasswd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.wbpasswd);
    submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
    fpass = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fpass);
    loginid = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loginid);
    password = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.password);
    fpass.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You have clicked the fpass button",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        });
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
             new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
            // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.ebharatgas.com/ebgas/login");

            try {
                // Add your data
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("wblogid", wblogid.getEditableText().toString()));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("wbpasswd", wbpasswd.getEditableText().toString()));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                String t = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                Intent i = new Intent("com.example.ebharatgas.Activity2");
                i.putExtra("code", t);
                startActivity(i); 

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            }
                    }
              }).start();
            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You have clicked the fpass button",
                    //Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        });

}
```

}

Also please tell me how can i display the response from the server on my android activity... and i am a beginner of android programming... please help me.... thanks in advance..

Comment: use asynctask and you display response in onPostExecute

Comment: actually i got an error to do the request process in a seperate thread so i did it... i guess the asynctask also does the same... iam getting response from server but its not the response iam expecting but an home page.... what is actually asynctask?

Comment: the http post code looks alright.

Answer (score 0):

give it a try like this:

private class JsonResponse extends AsyncTask {

```
    String response = "";

    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
    {   
        if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("Success"))
        {
        Intent i = new Intent("com.example.ebharatgas.Activity2");
            i.putExtra("code", t);
            startActivity(i); 
        }
    }
    protected String doInBackground(final String... args)
    {     List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("wblogid", wblogid.getEditableText().toString()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("wbpasswd", wbpasswd.getEditableText().toString()));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            String t = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

            }
                response = "Success";
        }
            catch(JSONException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            return response;
    }
} //Formatting & Code setting required
```

Comment: why 2 posts. you can edit your previous post and post and upvdate